# AKAppleSequencer with AKMIDISampler (sf2) plays only one note at a time in iO14

Tags: audiokit

Anyone with this problem? Playing a MIDI sequence using AKAppleSequencer is now playing only one note at a time on each channel.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: I have the same issue, using the AKMidiSampler with the AKAppleSequencer with AudioKit 4.10+ only effects iOS 14 devices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this a low level bug, after a day's work I do have a workaround: I noticed that the bug only kicks in if you have an AKMusicTrack with several notes that have the EXACT same position (like when you have a chord quantized). The workaround is very simple: add a tiny difference in the position. In my case I add Double(0.0001) to each note position that would fall to the exact same location. This difference is enough to avoid the bug, so all the notes sound. The human ear cannot tell such a tiny difference, so all's well until they actually fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its a tricky one and i guess experimental but if you follow the guide for [swift packages installation](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/v5-develop#swift-package-manager) select branch `v5-develop` then you can install the bleeding edge version. This does require a bit of a code overhaul though!!

Firstly the AudioKit is no longer static so the `start`, `stop` and output can't just be assigned. First you need to store an instance of the engine `let engine : AudioEngine` ... `engine = AudioEngine()` then you can start/stop assign output.

Secondly all the class names have changed. So the `AKMidiSampler` -> `MidiSampler` and `AKAppleSequencer` -> `AppleSequencer` etc so make sure all your namings are upto date. A bit of hunting through the framework will help you figure out what has changed.

Finally you will need to import `AVFoundation` as things like `AKDuration` have changed to `Duration` that is part of the core framework.